# Получить размер изображения?

Tags: php

Есть путь к изображению. Как получить ширину и высоту изображения по данному пути средствами PHP

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.getimagesize.php

Comment: можете попробовать воспользоваться этим [классом](https://github.com/StereoFlo/image-resize/blob/master/src/Image/ImageInfo.php)

Answer (score 0):

Самописная функция, которой я пользуюсь:

```
/** Возвращает массив с imageinfo если картинка, если нет файла или не картинка - false.
 * @param $local_img_path
 * @return array|bool
 */
function is_image($local_img_path)
{
    if (@is_file($local_img_path)) {
        if ($tmp = @getimagesize($local_img_path)) {
            if (@is_array($tmp)) {
                return $tmp;
            } else {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Если файл сущестует, и файл=картинка, будет возвращен массив с данными о картинке, например:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1024
    [1] => 691
    [2] => 2
    [3] => width="1024" height="691"
    [bits] => 8
    [channels] => 3
    [mime] => image/jpeg
)
```